# Should I start a discussion about something in StackOverflow?

Tags: support, questions

I have something I have been thinking for a while and I would like to start a discussion about it. In my opinion StackOverflow would be the most accessible place for professionals of my specialization (Salesforce). However, running discussions doesn't seem to be the purpose of StackOverflow.

[image]

Is there anything in StackOverflow specific for open discussions?